# Next JS Reviews Data Fetching

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, judge-api

I've been trying to integrate a review system into my website for a while at my client's request. My client's site is built with Shopify + Next JS. We pass the data from Shopify to Next JS with the Storefront API and build everything else with Next JS.

Here are a few methods we tried. Lastly, we tried transferring data to our site with Judge.me. We managed to fetch the data with the widget. But sometimes we found that the data did not come in when the page was first loaded. When we contacted them, unfortunately, the method they provided as a solution did not solve this problem. When I wanted to transfer the data to my project with the API, I could not get any data or I got a CORS error. According to them, they do not support client-side fetch. Instead they support server-side fetch. No matter how many methods I tried on this issue, the result was always the same. Unfortunately I didn't get any data.

Then I discovered Fera.ai while searching for alternatives. They have extensive developer documentation. (https://developers.fera.ai/reference/list-reviews-1) But I had the same problem trying to pull API data according to the methods they wrote in their documentation. I somehow did not transfer the data to my Next JS project.

[image: Fera.ai Reviews Fetching Image]

I can access the data when I query it from the browser URL. You can also see it at this link: https://api.fera.ai/v3/public/reviews?public_key=pk_330e6e13014044067752aadb350af9a067d660b696f561e91cdb0daa418b1438

In the project, are the methods I tried below not the right method for me to pull data with API? Where could I be doing wrong?

1. I tried to pull the data with `getServerSideProps`. With this method I only get the error:

   > "Error retrieving reviews data"

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function FeraReviews({ reviews }) {
if (!reviews) {
  return <div>Error retrieving reviews data</div>;
}

return (
  <div>
    <h1>Reviews</h1>
    <ul>
      {reviews.map((review) => (
        <li key={review.id}>
          <p>Author: {review.author}</p>
          <p>Rating: {review.rating}</p>
          <p>Comment: {review.comment}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.fera.ai/v3/public/reviews',
  params: { public_key: 'mytoken' },
  headers: { accept: 'application/json' },
};

try {
  const response = await axios.request(options);
  const reviews = response.data;

  return {
    props: {
      reviews,
    },
  };
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);

  return {
    props: {
      reviews: null,
    },
  };
}
}
```

2. I also tried to pull the data with axios.

```
// /pages/api

import axios from 'axios';

const options = {method: 'GET',url: 'https://api.fera.ai/v3/public/reviews',params: {public_key: 'pk_330e6e13014044067752aadb350af9a067d660b696f561e91cdb0daa418b1438'},headers: {accept: 'application/json'}};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {console.log(response.data);}).catch(function (error) {console.error(error);

});
```

3. If I try to fetch the data with `useEffect`, I naturally get a CORS error anyway.